# Angular.js : Translate not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-translate

I am using angular translate for localisation.

Here is my code :

```
var myObj.connected = false;
```

Html is :

```
<span translate>{{myObj.connected ? 'On' : 'Off'}}</span>
```

in my controller i am fetching the data from server and updating the "myObj.connected" on the basis of my response.
Things are working fine for Google Chrome but on IE-11 its not translating the values.

Comment: you should report this in the github repo. Have you tried the other syntaxes (and filter)?

Comment: Angular translate module support cross-browser compatibility (include IE 11). I've wrote a test and it works fine on IE 11. Because the value of 'myObj.connected' is determined by server response, maybe you could try to assign a hard coding value to it and check if this issue still exists.

Comment: @Chickenrice , with hardcode values it runs fine, but for dynamic values from the server it is not.. I mean it is showing the old value.

Answer (score 1):

Simple split it into two span:

```
<span ng-show="myObj.connected" translate>On</span>
<span ng-show="!myObj.connected" translate>Off</span>
```

remember to avoid use ng-if.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz Lubinski, it seems a work arround but, do you know the exact reason behind why this is happening ?

Comment: I have no idea. IE has his own rules ;) I found [link](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext/issues/59) but it seems to be not resolved yet.

Comment: Lukasz Lubinski : I will try to find something solid and update you too if got to know the exact reason... anyways, Thanks buddy :-)